# I use node-telegram-bot-api how can I make the bot wait for a response from the user?

Tags: javascript, bots

I use node-telegram-bot-api to make the bot wait for a response from the user

I am using a keyboard and I want the user to be able to enter data when I click on a certain value and I can further process it.

```
const personalData = {
    food: 0,
}


if (text === 'Food') {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Enter the amount')
        add('food', text)
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, `Spending on food:${personalData.food}`)
    }

const add = (category, sum) => {
    personalData[category] += +sum
}
```

And it turns out that my code immediately jumps to adding the amount to the object, instead of waiting for a response

I tried to use call back functions, but I still haven't got the hang of it.